# How to check if any word in a string has special characters and conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, where one column contains a tweet. I want to get the rows of this dataframe, where this "tweet" column contains any words that start with "#" and have 2 or more capital letters.

So for example, I want to retreive such rows:

- I love coding in python. #CodingSession
- I am not scared of #COVID19 anymore.

However, these would not classify under my conditions:

- I love coding in python. #Coding #Session
- I love coding in python. #Codingsession
- I am not scared of #Covid19 anymore.

Comment: Does '#coViD' should match?

Comment: Yes it should but I think @Corralien provided good enough answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `str.contains`:

```
df['Match'] = df['tweet'].str.contains(r'#[A-Z][^A-Z#]*[A-Z]')
print(df)

# Output
                                       tweet  Match
0    I love coding in python. #CodingSession   True
1        I am not scared of #COVID19 anymore   True
2  I love coding in python. #Coding #Session  False
3    I love coding in python. #Codingsession  False
4       I am not scared of #Covid19 anymore.  False
```

- `[A-Z]` for a capital letter
- `[^A-Z#]*` for anything else except capital letter or #
- `[A-Z]` and again a capital letter

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Jdv7uE/1)

Comment: Hello! Before your ambition +15, may I ask for where is 2 or more capital lteters in your regex

Comment: For the case of `coViD`, you can use `df['tweet'].str.contains(r'#[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z#]*[A-Z]')`